# How is Jack Burton very sure about the marks?

Tags: plot-explanation, big-trouble-in-little-china

In *Big Trouble in Little China*, Jack Burton and his Asian Friend Wang are trying to find **Maio Yin** in the building. They are disguised as telephone guys to enter into the Building.

At one point, Jack Burton saw some marks on the ground and then he says these words to Wang:

> What you got here is two people dragging a third.

[image]

So how is Jack very so sure about the marks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jack is speculating, but when delivered in his braggadocio and swagger, it sounds very confident.  Based on the character played, even when Jack Burton is 100% wrong about something, he probably sounds very sure that he is right.

It was a dusty room, and there were two sets of footprints, slightly more than shoulder width apart, and two narrow tracks of something dragged along the floor.

It's not the only explanation, but since they were looking for a woman who was abducted and carried off against her will, it fit with what they were expecting to find and what they were looking for, so Jack made the inferential leap.  He's a man of action, not contemplation and analysis!